# Calculate integrals using the arc length formula. What am I supposed to do? Why is it useful?

Tags: calculus, integration, arc-length

Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous differentiable function.
The curve $c_f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^2,\; t\mapsto \bigl(t,f(t)\bigr)$ is the parametrization of the graph of $f$.
The arc length of the graph of $f$ is
$$
L(c_f) = \int_{a}^{b} \! \sqrt { 1 + [f'(t)]^2 } \, dt.
$$

In an exercise it is explicitly said, that I should calculate the integrals

a) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^2 \, dx$

b) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} |2x| \, dx$

**using** the formula for the arc length $L$. I don't know how I can use the formula for $L$ to solve an integral and why I should do that? A part of the exercise is also to explain the geometrical meaning.

A hint is to use hyperbolic functions.

Those integrals are not complicated to solve:

a) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}x^2 \, dx = \biggl[\frac{x^3}{3}\biggr]_0^1 = \frac13$

b) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} |2x| \, dx = 2\int_{0}^{1} |x| \, dx = 2\int_{0}^{1}x \, dx = 2 \biggl[\frac{x^2}{2}\biggr]_0^1 = 1$

I'm confused about this exercise.  Does the exercise make any sense to you?

### Edit - Corrections and additional information based on the comments :

1)More context: I actually derived the formula of $L(c_f)$ in a previous exercise from the general formula for a continuous differentiable curve $L(c)= \int_{a}^{b} \!  || c'(t) || \, dt$. We derived this formula in our lectures, we started with the length of a polygon chain...We have done nothing further on this subject.

2)The exact phrasing of the exercise is: In the previous exercise, the formula of the arc length of the graph of a function $f$ was derived $L(c_f) = \int_{a}^{b} \! \sqrt { 1 + [f'(t)]^2 } \, dt$. With this in mind, calculate the integrals:

a) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^2 \, dx$

b) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} |2x| \, dx$ and explain the geometric meaning

### Edit 2

3. Perhaps the integrals should not be considered individually, there is another integral in the problem:

c) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+4x^2} \, dx$

I haven't written this until now as it seemed irrelevant to me, but maybe that was a mistake.

Comment: Hint: the parabola $y = x^2$ can be parameterized as $(x, y) = (t, t^2).$

Comment: Perhaps the intention is to recognize an integral (that you observe is easy to evaluate) *as the arc length calculation* for a given curve. Which curve over which interval of the parameter?

Comment: Are you sure that's what you were asked to do? What _would_ be an arc length is $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+((x^2)')^2}dx$, which can be proven with the suggested hyperbolic functions to be $\frac14(2\sqrt{5}+\ln(2+\sqrt{5}))$.

Comment: $g(x)=x^2=y\Rightarrow c_g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, t\mapsto (t,t^2)\Rightarrow L(c_g)=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt { 1 + [g'(t)]^2 }dt=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt { 1 + [2t]^2 }dt=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt { 1 + 4t^2 }dt  $.  Now one could do a substitution of the hyperbolic functions, but then I calculate the length of the edge of the area enclosed by the function $g(x)=x^2$, but not the integral of the function $g(x)$: $\int \limits_{0}^{1}x^2 dx$ Note: I started this comment before I saw the new ones, I will react as fast as I can to the new comments.

Comment: If this is from Stewarts calculus textbook the explanation should be abundantly clear. If it is not from Stewarts, I suggest you find a PDF of Stewarts and review the chapter on this for any confusion. Arc Length will be an important precursor to Line Integrals, which will be of great importance moving forward in your vector calculus studies.

Comment: @JohnColtraneisJC It is note from the textbook. More context: I actually derived the formula of $L(c_f)$ in a previous exercise from the general formula for a continuous differentiable curve $c:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R^n}$: $L(c)= \int_{a}^{b} \!  || f'(t) || \, dt$. We derived this formula  our lectures, we started with the length of a polygon chain...We have done nothing further on this subject.

Comment: @J.G. The exact phrasing is: In the previous exercise, the formula of the arc length of the graph of a function $f$ was derived $L(c_f) = \int_{a}^{b} \! \sqrt { 1 + [f'(t)]^2 } \, dt.$ With this in mind, calculate the integrals: a) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} x^2 \, dx$
b) $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} |2x| \, dx$ and explain the geometric meaning.

Comment: Correction: The general formula for a continuous differentiable curve $c:[a,b]→\mathbb{R}^n$ is $L(c)= \int_{a}^{b} \!  || c'(t) || \, dt$

Comment: I suspect the text was careless.

Comment: @SammyBlack Then the exercise would mean to find a function $f$ for which the arc length $L(c_f)$ is hard to calculate, so that I can use the easy integrals to calculate $L(c_f)$. That seems a bit strange to me, or did I misunderstand you? Because there is no curve given in the exercise.

Comment: It could be helpful to edit the question to include the additional context. That way people don’t have to wade through everyone else’s comments and your comments that you later had to correct in order to find out what you’re asking. Now is also the perfect time to correct errors in the question if you made any; this gets trickier once people start answering.

Comment: @DavidK Makes sense, I added the additional information.